# List tile color is covered by DecorationBox - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

The color of `ListTile` is converted to the color of `DecoratedBox`.

```dart
DecoratedBox(
                position: DecorationPosition.background,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Builder(builder: (context) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: screenWidth * 0.03,
                          vertical: screenHeight * 0.02,
                        ),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: ListTile(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            textColor: AppColors.white,
                            tileColor: AppColors.green,
                            title: Text("Title"),
                            // style: ListTileStyle.drawer,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Result:

[image: Output withcolor in DecoratedBox]

Once the Decorated box color is removed.

```dart
 DecoratedBox(
                position: DecorationPosition.background,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  // color: Colors.black,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Builder(builder: (context) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: screenWidth * 0.03,
                          vertical: screenHeight * 0.02,
                        ),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: ListTile(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            textColor: AppColors.white,
                            tileColor: AppColors.green,
                            title: Text("Title"),
                            // style: ListTileStyle.drawer,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Result:

[image: Output without color in DecoratedBox]

The actual color in the ListTile 'green' is visible.

Why the Decorated box color is applied for Listtile?

Any one help me.

**I need to solve by without adding extra widget.**

Comment: seems the issue is `DecoratedBox`'s is painted over `ListTile`'s color.

Comment: How to solve this.

Comment: you can try wrapping the item with any Material Widget

Comment: I have solved this by wrapping `ListTile` with the `DecoratedBox`. **But I need to solve by without adding extra widget.** Where I dont want to add an extra widget for the properties already use in ListTile.

Comment: add Material widget with type: MaterialType.transparency as your ListTile parent - read ListTile official docs why you need that Material parent

Answer (score 0):

try to add `tileColor` to your `ListTile`, you haven't defined it hence it is inheriting from parent and if parent have not defined it either it takes `selectedTileColor: AppColors.green`(that's my guess)

Comment: Already tried. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was following [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86584), you can wrap the `ListTile` with another `Material` widget.

```dart
Builder(builder: (context) {
  return Material(
    child: SizedBox(
```

Comment: I have solved this by wrapping ListTile with the DecoratedBox. **But I need to solve by without adding extra widget.** Where I dont want to add an extra widget for the properties already use in ListTile.

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to get. Not sure about the behavior but you can also try replacing ListTile with Row